# Linq select a range between two strings, such as Col thru Io

Tags: string, linq, range

How do I select a range of a strings between two values, such as those strings from "Col" thru "Io".

So If I were to perform this LINQ query on a list of the states within the U.S. It would return

```
Colorado, 
Connecticut, 
Delaware, 
Flordia, 
Georgia, 
Hawaii, 
Idaho, 
Illinoise, 
Indiana
```

but would not return Iowa since "Iowa" is after "Io".
This string is user entered, so its length can vary, or could be blank.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can try `from q in db.tablename where q.state >= @value1 and q.state <=@value2 select q`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two strings, use string.Compare(string1, string2)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx

```
List<String> states = new List<String> { "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Flordia", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinoise", "Indiana" };
List<String> filtered = states.Where(x => String.Compare(x, "D") > 0 && String.Compare(x, "If") < 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't this evaluate on the Client? It could be a performance issue on larger databases.